# Getting all form fields to validate at the same time including recaptcha

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, recaptcha

I had the form set with all the validation that happened at once, but I added the Google re-captcha and am wanting the following #grecaptchaError to appear when all the other errors appear.

Right now if everything is blank and  you hit submit the recaptcha error is the only one that shows...once you check the box to verify then the other errors appear.  The sitekey is correct for my domain and it works so please disregard the error in codepen.  Any help to rearrange the jquery would be appreciated.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/btreinhart/pen/zmMBYj)

```
function checkCaptcha() {
console.log('checkCaptcha');
if(allowSubmit) return true;
// e.preventDefault();
$('#grecaptchaError').text('Please confirm that you are not a robot');
return false;
```

}

**UPDATE:**

I found a callback method that checks a hidden value, and now all display errors show at the same time, I just know that the jquery is out of place because it loops right through without hitting the submit button and gives the success message. It started doing that when I added the `$.ajax({` towards the bottom.

New Codepen link is [here](https://codepen.io/btreinhart/pen/VEVGva)

Answer (score 0):

Your sequence of checking errors goes like captcha -> jQuery validation. That's why you don't seen the other error message because you are return if captcha error message comes.

I have updated your Javascript code so first your jQuery validation run and if it succeed then captcha check run.

```
  var allowSubmit = false;
  function captchaCb(response) {
    allowSubmit = true;
    console.log('this is reCaptcha response: ' + response);
  }
  function checkCaptcha() {
    console.log('checkCaptcha');
    if(allowSubmit) return true;
    // e.preventDefault();
    $('#grecaptchaError').text('Please confirm that you are not a robot');
    return false;
  }
  $("#form-submit").click(function() {
   $("#contact-form").submit();

  }); 
  $("#contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },
      budget: {
        required: true,
      },
      message: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
      },
    },
    messages: {
      name: {
       required: "come on, you have a name don't you?",
       minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
     },
     email: {
       required: "no email, no message"
     },
     budget: {
       required: "Please select your budget"
     },
     message: {
       required: "um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.",
       minlength: "thats all? really?"
     }
   },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "name" )  {
      error.appendTo('#nameError');
    }
    if (element.attr("name") == "email" )  {
      error.appendTo('#emailError');
    }
    if (element.attr("name") == "budget" )  {
      error.appendTo('#budgetError');
    }
  if (element.attr("name") == "g-recaptcha-response" )  {
      error.appendTo('#grecaptchaError');
    }
    if (element.attr("name") == "message" )  {
      error.appendTo('#messageError');
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

  if (!checkCaptcha()) {
      console.log('captcha error occurs ');
     return;
    }
    $.ajax({
      //dataType: "jsonp",
      url: "example.com",
      data: $("#contact-form").serialize()
    }).done(function() {
      //callback which can be used to show a thank you message
      //and reset the form
      $("#contact-form").hide();
      $(".form-thank-you").fadeIn("400");
    });
      return false; //to stop the form from submitting
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and help.  We're almost there, and the field errors now show, but for some reason when the captcha is empty it doesn't show the error in the checkCaptcha() function.

Comment: @breinhart For that change form submit function `$("#form-submit").click(function() {
   $("#contact-form").submit();

  });` to `$("#form-submit").click(function() {
   checkCaptcha(); $("#contact-form").submit(); });`

Comment: I changed the function to  `$("#form-submit").click(function() { 
  checkCaptcha(); $("#contact-form").submit(); 
 });` and also updated the codepen, but for some reason it still doesn't seem to be giving the recaptcha error.  Your logic makes since, I just feel like I'm missing a small part as to why.

Comment: @breinhart is your captcha validation uses any server api ( ajax call ). if yes then you have to wait for the promise to resolve and then call the form submit ajax.

Comment: Yes it uses the standard recaptcha API javascript.  Please see update above...I was able to figure out getting all errors to show at once but my jquery is clearly out of place. If you take a look at the new pen you might be able to help so that the form actually waits for submit to be pressed.  I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: @breinhart For validation based on the response from server api you have to handle differently. hiddenRecaptcha validate method should implement like this `hiddenRecaptcha: {
              required:true,
              remote: {
                    url: "aprocess.php",
                    type: "post",
                    success: function(response) {if (response.responseText == "true") {} else {}}}}`. For reference follow this link - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-use-remote-methode-in-validate

Comment: thank you...It's been a crazy last few weeks.  I'll look into it further.